# Where did I go wrong on this test question comparing film and novels?

Tags: comparison

I was given a test, and asked to complete this sentence:

> On many college campuses, the study of film has become ________ .

With one of these five choices:

> **A**. as common as that of the novel 
>    **B**. like the novel, as common 
>    **C**. common, as is that of the novel 
>    **D**. as common as the novel's study 
>    **E**. just as the novel's study is common

I picked choice **D**, but was told the  correct answer is **A**. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Hey man. What would you like to know?

Comment: You will get better answers if (a) you actually ask a question; (b) you explain why you picked D. That gives answerers something to focus on.

Comment: why i got it wrong??

Comment: And what of "explain why you picked D"? I'll reopen this now there is a question, but we do expect **a lot** of effort put into questions, I'm afraid.

Comment: there is alotta effort put in it, i want help not snide comments

Comment: @BernardAkoto Attitude is rewarded in kind. If you're pleasant with us, you'll find us warm and welcoming with you. I promise. Also, it's worth considering that you're on a site full of people who love English and pay attention to the details of how it is used, e.g. capitalization, punctuation, use of formal vs informal register, etc: these are all things we notice,  and take great care of in our own writing. To that end, I've gone ahead and edited your question to improve its overall formatting, which will influence its reception. You can use it as a model for further questions and comments.

Comment: There's a difference between *"the novel's study"* and *"the study of the novel"*. If D had said *"... the study of the novel"*, it would also have been correct.

Comment: I think this question would be better received at [ELL.se].

Comment: There is nothing actually 'incorrect' about option D. It is just that in my own opinion A is better because it avoids repetition of the word *study*.

Comment: I don't blame you for being confused.  A is the most straight-forward choice, but C and D are technically correct, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Usually genitives in *-'s* and preposition phrases headed by *of* mean pretty much the same thing; but when these modify nouns which are derived from active verbs or have an active sense there is usually a distinction:

- A genitive designates the Subject/Agent of the underlying verb
- An *of* PP designates the Object/Patient of the underlying verb.

For instance, in analyzing Thomas Mann's *Dr. Faustus* we might write about

> the novel's study of artistic genius

Here we mean that the novel<sup>subject</sup> studies artistic genius<sup>object</sup>.

Consequently, your D and E imply incorrectly that the study is performed **by** the novel, while A and C imply correctly that the study is performed **upon** the novel, just as other study is performed **upon** film.

It's not a hard-and-fast rule. A verb-derived noun which in context may be understood to express a passive meaning, in which the Subject is the Patient acted upon, may take a genitive expressing the Subject/Patient.

> We're celebrating John's<sup>subject/agent</sup> completion of his novel<sup>object/patient</sup> = *John has completed the novel*
>   We're celebrating the novel's<sup>subject/**patient**</sup> completion = *The novel has been been completed*

Comment: I was with you all the way, but then how about "*the novel's completion*" ?? (You've still got my +1, becuase I'm certain you,ve got a good answer:)

Comment: @Araucaria: A novel can be in a *state* of completion, so the issue of agency isn't relevant there, and thus the possessive is OK.  We can say *the novel's publication* but not (not really) *the novel's publishing*. Agency comes back into the picture with the -ing form.

Comment: @Araucaria I think Tim Romano nails it -- that's what I meant by an 'active' meaning. I confused grammatical and thematic functions. I'll fix.

Comment: Compare 'The cooking of tilapia is now as common as the cooking of ling' with ??/*'Tilapia's cooking is now as common as ling's'.  It's not idiomatic to substitute the Saxon genitive for the of-phrase in all circumstances; it's certainly the patient-referencing of-phrase (ie re the undergoer rather than the doer) that resists here ('Tilly's cooking is now every bit as good as Lana's' is fine).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was very confused by your comment until I realized that tilapia and ling are fish, not cooks :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Stoney - me too! Ha ha!

Comment: i understand where i went wrong now ; 'the novel's study' actually mean the study was performed by the novel, the "tilipia" example really clarified it very well.